# Wordpress displays the wrong taxonomy for a custom post type on the edit page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

The problem is that only on the edit page of custom post type it shows the taxonomy from Post type and not taxonomy associated with this post type. It correctly shows at Quick Edit post block: [image]

But it doesn't show correctly on the edit page, it shows the taxonomy of the post:
[image]

The code which I'm using:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {    
    register_taxonomy( 'categories', array( 'blog' ), [
    'labels'                => [
        'name'              => 'Blog Categories',
            'singular_name'     => 'Blog Category',
    ],
    'public'            => true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
    ] );

    register_post_type( 'blog', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'           => 'Blog posts',
            'singular_name'  => 'Blog post'
        ),
        'public'       => true,
    'has_archive'  => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports'     => array('title','editor', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'   => array( 'categories' ),
    ) );
} );
```

I can't figure out where the glitch is and why the taxonomy works fine, but doesn't show up on the edit page.

I updated the friendly URL and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to 1st user register_post_type method and after that use register_taxonomy() . May be it work